# How many concurrent MySQL connections are allowed with Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

How many max users can concurrently use MySQL database? I am using Hibernate Implementation of JPA.

Answer (score 2):

That is more specific to database side.i believe you can always set number of threads in your database 
for mysql you need to set following in `my.ini`

```
max_connections=2
```

However you might also want to set this:

```
thread_cache_size=1
```

The thread cache controls how many it keeps open even when nothing is happening.

regarding hibernate side if you are not using connection pool hibernate tend to get database connection for the unit of work and return it back moment its done with it work.

you can always define you connection pooling in hibernate using `c3p0` API

[c3p0 Connection pooling in hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)